# send a email after user data is saved Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

i want to send email to user after data is saved how do i pass the data like "first_name" to the email function how do i pass the data without data i have able call the email function its working.

```
from Email import views as em

    @api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
def CustomerAPI(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        snippets = Customer.objects.all()
        serializer = CustomerSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return Response({"Customer_List": serializer.data})


    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            #em.email_send1(request, first_name='SOURABH', middle_name='k', last_name='SAIKIA')
            #response = em.email_send1(request=request._request).data
            response = em.email_send1(request=request._request.POST["first_name"]="sourabh").data
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `User` object via `request.user`. For example:

```
em.email_send1(request, first_name=request.user.first_name, last_name=request.user.last_name)
```

Note that the default Django `User` model (from [`django.contrib.auth`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model)) doesn't have a middle-name attribute.

Comment: i have done how u suggest but error File "D:\Restro App\my_django_project\app_api\viewsapi.py", line 49, in CustomerAPI
    response = em.email_send1(request, first_name='SOURABH', last_name='SAIKIA')
 File "D:\Restro App\my_django_project\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\request.py", line 157, in __init__
    .format(request.__class__.__module__, request.__class__.__name__)
AssertionError: The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `rest_framework.request.Request`.
[29/Sep/2020 17:15:21] "POST /api/APICUSTOMER/ HTTP/1.1" 500 126345

Comment: @Saurabhkumar your `email_send1` method needs a standard Django `HttpRequest` object instead of a REST Framework `Request` argument. Since `CustomerAPI` is a REST Framework view, it passes a REST `Request` object when it calls your method. Could you provide details of that `email_send1` method? Maybe it can do without that parameter, but I can't tell without knowing more about it.